# changing size of alert dialog using theme in android

Tags: android

is there any theme same as this R.style.Theme_Dialog but with bigger size and text appearence for title and buttons for alert dialog?

I already know how to make  an alert dialog but in big screen sizes the alert dialog seems to be very small with respect to screen and it doesn't changes it's size according to screen.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is there a theme for that. But to address the

1. Font issue- Please write fonts in both values/dimens.xml and values-large/dimens.xml. So for bigger screens, the bigger font value will be used.
2. For dialog size issue, you can use this code

Display display = (context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

```
Point size = new Point();

        try {
            display.getSize(size);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError ignore) {

            size.x = display.getWidth();
            size.y = display.getHeight();


        }
        int width = size.x;
        d.getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * widthFactor),
                heightFactor);
```

Here the dialog size will be relative to screen size. If you set widthFactor=0.90, the dialog will take 90% of the screen width.

Comment: actually i know how to do it this way but i was hoping to find another theme with same styling but bigger, thanks anyway